# jQuery add new table row upon entering data into quantity field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I'd like to add new rows to the end of my table upon user entering data into the quantity field.

My table is below. I am using Bootstrap 3.1.1, as well as jQuery 1.11

Essentially, it is a Quick Order form. I want to be able to provide the user with enough fields to fill out all the time.

```
<div class="container White_BG">
    <div class="row" style="margin-left:0;margin-right:0;">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <h1>Quickly place your order with this form.</h1>
            <h2>Please enter the item numbers that you wish to order; once you add to the cart, then you will be able to change the quantity of those items ordered.</h2>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <form method="post" name="QuickOrderMulti">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="active">Item #</th>
                            <th class="active">Quantity</th>
                            <th class="active">Description</th>
                            <th class="active">Price</th>
                            <th class="active">Subtotal</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-lg-2 ProductNumber"><input type="text" name="ProductNumber"></td>
                            <td class="col-lg-2 Quantity"><input type="text" name="Quantity"></td>
                            <td class="col-lg-2 QuickDescription"></td>
                            <td class="col-lg-2 QuickPrice"></td>
                            <td class="col-lg-2 QuickSubtotal"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-default btn-orange">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the .append() method in jQuery. Eg:

```
$('.table').append(table_row_data);
```

Where `table_row_data` is a string version of the row you want to insert

So if you wanted the rows created based on the quantity, you could do:

```
var quantity = $('td.Quantity input').val();
for(var i=0; i<quantity; i++) {
    $('.table').append(table_row_data);
}
```

Although, you might want to put an id on the Quantity input field so your jQuery search can be a bit more specific. Then you could wrap it all in an event like:

```
$('#quantity_input').on("change", function() {
    var quantity = $(this).val();
    for(var i=0; i<quantity; i++) {
        $('.table').append(table_row_data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, so how would I wrap that in code to check if the quantity field has value? If it has value, that's when I want to provide a new row.

Comment: What do you mean by "is a string version of the row you want to insert"? Just all on 1 line?

Comment: Ok, I somewhat have it working here:

http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/quickorder.aspx

But when I enter a qty into the newly added row, it doesn't add anymore new rows.

Comment: It looks as though you are using the quantity to mean two different things. One refers to the number of different items the person will order, and the other for how many of that type they will order. What about if you put a quantity box at the top of the table with a label: 'Enter the number of different items you wish to order' or something like that? Then that will determine how many rows to insert, with a different item quantity box per row. Does that make sense?